# model messages on django

Tags: django, django-models

I created a model for messages. Users may have many messages. Messages can be read by many users.

Similar to group chat in Slack.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    users_read = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='read_messages')
    date_created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Is this the correct way to references these in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right but you can use `Chat` model alongside with `Message`.

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='chats')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500) # what length you want
```

This structure lets you to easily track your messages and chats.